# Converting from if else statement to switch case

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have the following if else statement to check the values of prices. However, I'm just curious of how can I be able to convert it to a switch statement.

```
if(sellingPrice <= costPrice)
{
    Response.Write("<script>alert('The value of the selling price must be higher than the cost price!','_self')</script>");
}
else if(sellingPrice == 0)
{
    Response.Write("<script>alert('The value of the selling price must not be equal to zero!','_self')</script>");
}
else if(costPrice == 0)
{
    Response.Write("<script>alert('The value of the cost price must not be equal to zero!','_self')</script>");
}
else
{
    con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = ARIES - PC\SQLEXPRESS; AttachDbFilename = D:\Visual Studio 2015 Web Forms\POS_with_Inventory\Database\Point_Of_Sales.mdf;Integrated Security = True");
    con.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("addStocks", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ProductID", productId);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ProductName", itemName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ProductCategory", category);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ProductDesc", description);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ProductCostPrice", costPrice);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ProductSellingPrice", sellingPrice);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ProductQuantity", quantity);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("RemainingProduct", quantity);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ProductPurchased", datePurchased);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ProductStatus", status);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.Dispose();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: You won't gain anything from forcing this into a switch statement because you need to evaluate a range (smaller-or-equal). The only (subjective) improvement imho would be to have seperate if blocks and explicitly return from those to make it clear that certain conditions stop the program flow.

Comment: case statment expect a constant value .. in your case you have Costprice seems to be non-constant value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cases you show are:

- One comparision between A and B
- check if A is 0
- check if B is 0

This is just plain out of the range of a switch. You would need to get it down to checking only one value (A or B) vs a constant.

This rule has been slightly eroded with C# 7.0, by the addition of [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching) for switch. But I am pretty sure that the rule that you can only switch on a single value still holds true.

Edit: Actually, with pattern matching it would be possible. You would have to move A and B into a single type (struct, tuple, anonymous type). But once oyu do that, the when clause would allow you to pull it off (when a.SellPrice == a.BuyPrice). But it really is a question if that would be worth the effort.

Edit 2: Let#s write some code on the idea I had. I am not sure this will compile, but it has a solid case.

```
switch(priceGroup){
  case prices p when p.sellingPrice <= p.costPrice:
    break;
  case prices p when p.sellingPrice == 0:
    break;
  case prices p when p.costPrice == 0:
    break;
}
```

Comment: @user9405863: That it is not possible is a valid answer in all the books I ever read. Of course I just realised it is possible, by using a temporary type and when clauses.